# PHP/MySQL Dropdown not showing selected results in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have been reading and looking for a solution for my current problem with no luck. I currently have a php page which fetches dates from mysql into a drop-down table perfectly, but when selecting it it takes me to the result page and does not show anything. If anyone could assist me with this, i would be very grateful.

This is the select code:

```
<div class="span6" style="text-align: center">
    <h4 style="text-align: center">Monthly Tax Search</h4>
    <br>
    <table>
        <thead>

        </thead>
    </table>
    <form action="tax-monthly-report.php" method="post">
        <?php

        $query = "select date_format(date,'%b %Y') 'date',SUM(siit.tax_amount) 'tax_amount',st.tax_description 'tax_description'
                  from si_invoices si
                  inner join si_invoice_items sii on si.id = sii.invoice_id
                  inner join si_invoice_item_tax siit on sii.id = siit.invoice_item_id
                  inner join si_tax st ON siit.tax_id = st.tax_id
                  GROUP BY date_format(date,'%b %Y')";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
        echo '<select name="date">';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['date'] ."'>" . $row['date'] ."</option>";
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit" />
              <input type="reset"  class="btn btn-danger" name="RESET" value="Cancel" />';
        ?>
    </form>

</div>
```

So here you can see that even though it does have the complete query it is only so to select the date which will be referenced with the table on the other page, here is the code for the result page:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6" style="text-align: center">
    <h4 style="text-align: center">Monthly Tax Search</h4>
        <br>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Tax Type</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
<?
$date = $_POST['date'];
$query = "select date_format(date,'%b %Y') 'date',SUM(siit.tax_amount) 'tax_amount',st.tax_description 'tax_description'
      from si_invoices si
      left join si_invoice_items sii on si.id = sii.invoice_id
      left join si_invoice_item_tax siit on sii.id = siit.invoice_item_id
      left join si_tax st ON siit.tax_id = st.tax_id
      WHERE date =  '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."'
      GROUP BY st.tax_description,date_format(date,'%b %Y')";

        if($num_result == 1) {
        echo '<b>ERROR</b>';
        }

$result =mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_errno());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '  <tr>
                            <td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row['tax_description'] . '</td>
                            <td style="text-align: right">'."$ " . number_format($row['tax_amount'],2) . '</td>
                        </tr>';
            }
?>
                  </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to convert the `$_POST['date']` value to correct format in fetching record after submitting the first form since you have converted mysql format to `%b %Y`

Have you checked by printing the query and execute that directly in mysql client or phpmyadmin?

Comment: I have run the query through MySQl Workbench and it works fantastically without a single error. With and without the DATE_FORMAT or %b %Y.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to convert the $_POST['date'] value @Yogesh

Comment: You can convert date to time using strtotime and then use `PHP date` function to convert it to mysql format that you have. **OR** you can set original date value without formatting in `SELECT TAG` in value attribute so that you will not need to convert it back to mysql format

Comment: So i took your advice, i strip'd the DATE_FORMAT and just left it as date (si.date AS date) and it worked like a charm! So all i have todo is format the date in PHP instead of the Query!

Comment: Welcome :) Glad to see this helped